# 19bit ADC with 16 bit output

Tags: math, embedded, sensors

https://www.melexis.com/en/documents/documentation/application-notes/application-note-mlx90393-getting-started-guide

I have the above magnetometer and am having a hard time understanding the effective range of the 19bit ADC in context of the 16bit output. Are resolution 2 and 3 (see page 17) just a smaller window over the same sampled data that are available in resolution 0 and 1 or do I need to shift the 16 bit output by corresponding number of bits to find its full value?
[image]
I think I already understand the sensitivity just cant quite figure out how to construct the #s from the digital filter before turning it into real units (mGauss in this case) for each of the 3 resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

It's specified, the resolution is 19 bits. So internally you have a 19 bit value. But the output of the sensor is just 16 bit so you must choose which 16 bits you are interested into and forget the others.

With resolution 2, 3 you obtain a value which is in a different scale. For example at resolution 2 you discard two least significant bits. This mean that the value has a scale which is 4x compared to the value you would read in 0 scaling. If the sensor returns 1 then it's 1 << 2 = 4.

So whatever is the unit you are using, you must take care to adjust the value (eg shift values to the left and pad with zero assuming your resolution ignores such small values).

Comment: This makes sense however I am unsure why  the value is centered around 0uT = 2^15 in the case of res. 2 & 3 (mentions this on pg 18), while 0 for res 0 & 1. How it handles 2s complement is also somewhat confusing for me, is the leading 1 always at index [18].

Comment: No great mystery about the sign and MSB if you consider the range of legal non-overflowing values for a given format.  And the unsigned values are simply offset by half the range.

Answer (score 0):

Shifting the 16 bit value left by any number of bits will not add any information, it will simply scale the value - unnecessarily.

The 19bit internal representation is largely irrelevant to you; that is just an implementation detail - you only need concern yourself with the sensitivity and range and select the resolution mode and gain value that best suits your application.

Unless your application places the sensor in a temperature controlled environment, you probably should ignore resolution modes 2 and 3 in any case.

The manner in which the range and type described in the table is somewhat confusing perhaps and not clarified in the text.  For the unsigned values, the sensor value needs transposing to a signed value:

```
int16_t sensor_value = (int16_t)((int32_t)sensor_value_adc - 0x8000) ;
```

Given the selection of resolution and gain (and therefore sensitivity), the output in mGauss is then:

```
double mgauss = sensor_value * sensor_sensitivity_uT * 10.0 ;  // 1 uT = 10mG
```